# Automatically xampp shutdown when computer start

Tags: mysql, xampp

```
6:29:08 PM  [mercury]   Run this program from your XAMPP root directory!
6:29:08 PM  [Tomcat]    Problem detected: Tomcat Not Found!
6:29:08 PM  [Tomcat]    Disabling Tomcat buttons
6:29:08 PM  [Tomcat]    Run this program from your XAMPP root directory!
6:29:08 PM  [Tomcat]    Problem detected: Required Tool catalina_start.bat  Not Found!
6:29:08 PM  [Tomcat]    Problem detected: Required Tool catalina_stop.bat Not Found!
6:29:08 PM  [Tomcat]    Problem detected: Required Tool catalina_service.bat Not Found!
```

6:29:08 PM  [main]   Starting Check-Timer
   6:29:08 PM  [main]   Control Panel Ready

I installed xampp and use correctly.if shut down my computer and start xampp apache,mysql,and all options buttons disabled.then again i uninstall and insatll xampp this time worked.but if computer shutdown and start xampp not worked.i googled dll is missing something like.but not work.what is the problem exactly.anybody guide me.
how to take backup my existing databases.i cant know how to retrieve my database files.